# Popping the [party] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

We have a [party](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/party) tag. Its a metatag. It needs popping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We *had* a party tag. It was *unambigiously* a meta tag, and only had 3 posts using it. One was grossly off topic. The other two did not suffer from lack of it.

The party is over.

Comment: Gah! Take my useless downvote for popping the party!

Answer (score 0):

Party pooper. *sad smiley face*